# Is there any method to make computeds columns have 2 parameters as range?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, calculated-columns

I'm trying to create a procedure where, declared the variables initialized and having created a computed column, the average value has the variables @ efinal1 and @ efinal2 as ranges

```sql
create proc sppromediorango

@efinal1 int=0,--min value
@efinal2 int=10--max value
as
begin
--here i make a computed column for getting the average score 
select ([ScoreEParcial]*0.4+[ScoreEFinal]*0.6)as averagescore
from [dbo].[tbAlumnos] a inner join [dbo].[tbScore] c 
on (a.aluID=c.ScoreAluID)
--here i´m looking for a correct method
where  averagescore between @efinal1 and @efinal2

end
go
```

I´m expecting an output having @efinal1 and @efinal2 as range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use aliases from the `select` clause in the `where` clause.
You need to either use a derived table or a common table expression. (the only difference in this case is readability):

```
create proc sppromediorango

    @efinal1 int=0,--min value
    @efinal2 int=10--max value
as
begin

    select averagescore
    from
    (
        select ([ScoreEParcial]*0.4+[ScoreEFinal]*0.6)as averagescore
        from [dbo].[tbAlumnos] a 
        inner join [dbo].[tbScore] c 
        on (a.aluID=c.ScoreAluID)
    ) As derived
    where  averagescore between @efinal1 and @efinal2

end
go
```